# Is the permutation in $S_1$ even or odd?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

A permutation is even or odd depending on whether it can be written as an even or odd number of transpositions. However, the permutation in $S_1$ cannot be written as a product of transpositions, so is it just undefined?

Comment: It can be written as the product of $0$ transpositions.

Comment: Its subgroup $A_1$ is the group of even permutations. Since $\{ e \}<A_1<S_1=\{e\}$ (where $e$ is the identity of $S_1$), we have $S_1=A_1$ so $e$ is even.

Comment: The sign of a permutation can be thought of as the determinant of the corresponding permutation matrix. And the determinant of $[1]$ is $1$.

Comment: This follows from the same idea that an empty sum is equal to zero, and an empty product is equal to $1$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be written as the product of $0$ transpositions, and $0$ is an even number, making it an even permutation. This is not just true of the permutation in $S_1$, it's true of the identity element in every symmetric group $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Since zero is even, what can we conclude?